# Use of (a | (a+1) ) in programming

Tags: bitmask

What is the use of a | (a+1) .
Where i can get all the hacks regarding bit manipulation other than geeksforgeeks.

I use this concept on multiple examples but that doesn't make any pattern so that we can use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns on the rightmost zero bit in the word.

Get a copy of Hacker's Delight. Basics, page 11. A great book.

Comment: Did you mean it toggle rightmost zero bit of the number?

Comment: Let a=9 then (a+1)=10. In binary format a=1001 and (a+1)=1010.                  
When we take bitwise OR of a number (a) and (a+1) then the result is 1011. The rightmost zero bit of a number (a) becomes 1  and no other changes occur in that number.